OneNote on macOS always forces Kerberos authentication
I have set up Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and would like to access OneNote notebooks from macOS OneNote app.
Whenever I try to access it I am shown a window which asks for Kerberos credentials:

But there is no Kerberos on my SharePoint server, I am using Basic Auth or NTLM Auth.
And if I try to enter my credentials, it says Domain can't be empty. And when I enter a domain (like LOCALHOST or the name of my SharePoint server) I get "unable to reach any KDC in realm LOCALHOST ...".
Why is this? Is there any way to disable Kerberos and/or use macOS OneNote app with Sharepoint Foundation 2013?
